# can't get hardware accelerated graphics with linux mint 13

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics

When I do a search for additional drivers I get no result. But I know that such driver exists because I had accelerated graphics on this computer before when i run ubuntu 10-04 on it. I have no clue how to begin trubleshoot this.
The computer is a laptop : `LG E500-G-APCCV` with this graphics: `Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel hardware is sometiems called integrated graphics, neverthless it is still accerlated.

Intel graphics on Linux are not closed source binary blobs like Nvidia and hence are not considered under the "additional drivers".

Most likely you have the acceleartion turned on.

If you notice poor performance it is because your graphics hardware is old.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I activated opengl and some more things in compiz, (following a youtube video) and accelerated graphics works just fine now.